# Tried to access session data without an active access token laravel

Tags: php, laravel, access-token

I have the code below to generate access token using LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Authorizer and I need to get the authId for the audit log.

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', ['middleware' => $pre_token_middleware, 
function () {

    $access_token = Authorizer::issueAccessToken();

    // Create log for logged in user
    $auth_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
    // another code here..

    return \Response::json($access_token);
}]);
```

But I get Tried to access session data without an active access token error when the `getResourceOwnerId` function is executed. I already tried moving the code to a controller but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this bunddle(How it functional/work) but I think you missed something. Check below detail from [lucadegasperi-oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/getting-started/middlewares.md).

If the middlewares isn't in the correct order, methods like the `Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId()` wont work.

Please note that the middlewares has to be applied in a certain order. The `OAuthMiddleware` has to be added before the `OAuthClientOwnerMiddleware` and the `OAuthUserOwnerMiddleware`

May this information will help you!

**UPDATE**
Try below middleware code

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function () {

    Route::get('authroute', function() {
        //OAuth will be required to access this route
    });

    Route::post('postwithauth', function(Request $request) {
        $userID = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
        $input = $request->input();
        return response()->json(array('userID' => $userID, 'input' => $input));
    });

});
```

Here `authroute` and `postwithauth` need to update with your one.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. I realized that I need to use the oauth middleware to make it work. But I still need to find a way to get the user id on the same login endpoint.

Comment: If you want to use/know current logged in user if after logged in, try printing `Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: @user2063370 Check my **UPDATE**

Comment: Auth::user()->id; solved my problem! You saved my day, thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help you...! Marry Xmas. Cheer!